# Removing beginnings sequences in fasta from a list with size

Tags: bash

I want to remove specific sequence in the list with IDs and extract sequence from large fasta file.

input test.fasta file:

```
>GHAT8X
MKFNDIRNDGHEDCFNNIIFASKLSSHKNVLKLTGCCLETRIPVIVFESVKNRTLADHIYQNQPHFEPLLLSQRLRIAVHIANAIAYLHIGFSRPILHRKIRPSRIFLDEGYIAKLFDFSLSVSIPEGETCVKDKVTGTMGFLAPEYI
>GHAMNO
MRLIGCCLETENPVLVFEYVEYGTLADRIYHPRQPNFEPVTCSLRLKIAMEIAYGIAYLHVAFSRPIVFRNVKPSNILFQEQSVAKLFDFSYSESIPEGETRIRGRVMGTFGYLPPEYIATGDCNEKCDVYSFGMLLLELLTGQRAVD
>GHAXM6
MYSCLGAIKNSGKEDKEKCIMRNGKNLLENLISSFNDGETHIKDAIPIGIMGFVATEYVTTGDYNEKCDVFSFGVLLLVLLTGQKLYSIDEAGDRHWLLNRVKKHIECNTFDEIVDPVIREELCIQSSEKDKQVQAFVELAVKCVSES
```

seqid_len.txt file:

```
GHAT8X 25
GHAMNO 26
GHAXM6 20
```

Expected output:

```
>GHAT8X
SSHKNVLKLTGCCLETRIPVIVFESVKNRTLADHIYQNQPHFEPLLLSQRLRIAVHIANA
IAYLHIGFSRPILHRKIRPSRIFLDEGYIAKLFDFSLSVSIPEGETCVKDKVTGTMGFLA
PEYI
>GHAMNO
ADRIYHPRQPNFEPVTCSLRLKIAMEIAYGIAYLHVAFSRPIVFRNVKPSNILFQEQSVA
KLFDFSYSESIPEGETRIRGRVMGTFGYLPPEYIATGDCNEKCDVYSFGMLLLELLTGQR
AVD
>GHAXM6
MRNGKNLLENLISSFNDGETHIKDAIPIGIMGFVATEYVTTGDYNEKCDVFSFGVLLLVL
LTGQKLYSIDEAGDRHWLLNRVKKHIECNTFDEIVDPVIREELCIQSSEKDKQVQAFVEL
AVKCVSES
```

I tried:

```
sed 's/_/|/g' seqid_len.txt | while read line;do grep -i -A1 ${line%%[1-9]*} test.fasta | seqkit subseq -r ${line##[a-z]* }:-1 ; done
```

**Only getting GHAT8X 25 and GHAMNO 26 sequence out. However, renaming the header does not work.**

Any correction on this or any python solution would be really helpful.
Have a great weekend.
Thanks

Comment: I don't see Python in your question so I removed tag `python` and add `bash`

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'NR==FNR {a[">" $1] = $2 + 0; next}         # create an array which maps the header to the starting position of the sequence
    $0 in a {                                   # the header matches an array index
        start = a[$0]                           # get the starting position
        print                                   # print the header
        getline                                 # read the sequence line
        print substr($0, start)                 # print the sequence by removing the beginnings
    }
' seqid_len.txt test.fasta | fold -w 60         # wrap the output within 60 columns
```

Output:

```
>GHAT8X
SSHKNVLKLTGCCLETRIPVIVFESVKNRTLADHIYQNQPHFEPLLLSQRLRIAVHIANA
IAYLHIGFSRPILHRKIRPSRIFLDEGYIAKLFDFSLSVSIPEGETCVKDKVTGTMGFLA
PEYI
>GHAMNO
ADRIYHPRQPNFEPVTCSLRLKIAMEIAYGIAYLHVAFSRPIVFRNVKPSNILFQEQSVA
KLFDFSYSESIPEGETRIRGRVMGTFGYLPPEYIATGDCNEKCDVYSFGMLLLELLTGQR
AVD
>GHAXM6
IMRNGKNLLENLISSFNDGETHIKDAIPIGIMGFVATEYVTTGDYNEKCDVFSFGVLLLV
LLTGQKLYSIDEAGDRHWLLNRVKKHIECNTFDEIVDPVIREELCIQSSEKDKQVQAFVE
LAVKCVSES
```

You'll see the 3rd sequence starts with `IMR..`, one column shifted compared with your expected `MRN..`. If the 3rd one is correct and the 1st and the 2nd sequences should be fixed, tweak the calculation `$2 + 0` as `$2 + 1`.

Comment: Hi tshiono, The "\" in the sequence can be ignored, i had added them for new lines. It works. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer accordingly. If you consider your problem is well solved with my answer, I'd appreciate if you can accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.